# binding a table to a dictionary in telerik reporting c#

Tags: c#, telerik-reporting

I want to bind a table to a list of objects, each object has a IDictionary.

```
public ObjectInstance
{
        public IDictionary<string, object> Dictionary { get; set; }
```

The source is a `IEnumerable<ObjectInstance>`
I've tried this with no success:

```
    void table1_ItemDataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //create two HtmlTextBox items (one for header and one for data) which would be added to the items collection of the table
        Telerik.Reporting.HtmlTextBox textboxGroup;
        Telerik.Reporting.HtmlTextBox textBoxTable;


        //we do not clear the Rows collection, since we have a details row group and need to create columns only
        this.table1.ColumnGroups.Clear();
        this.table1.Body.Columns.Clear();
        this.table1.Body.Rows.Clear();
        int i = 0;
        this.table1.ColumnHeadersPrintOnEveryPage = true;
        var attributes = _objectInstances.First().ObjectType.Attributes;
        foreach (var attribute in attributes)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attribute.ColumnName)) continue;


            var tableGroupColumn = new Telerik.Reporting.TableGroup();
            this.table1.ColumnGroups.Add(tableGroupColumn);
            this.table1.Body.Columns.Add(new Telerik.Reporting.TableBodyColumn(Unit.Inch(1)));


            textboxGroup = new Telerik.Reporting.HtmlTextBox();
            textboxGroup.Style.BorderColor.Default = Color.Black;
            textboxGroup.Style.BorderStyle.Default = BorderType.Solid;
            textboxGroup.Value = attribute.ColumnName;
            textboxGroup.Size = new SizeU(Unit.Inch(1.1), Unit.Inch(0.3));
            tableGroupColumn.ReportItem = textboxGroup;


            textBoxTable = new Telerik.Reporting.HtmlTextBox();
            textBoxTable.Style.BorderColor.Default = Color.Black;
            textBoxTable.Style.BorderStyle.Default = BorderType.Solid;
            textBoxTable.Value = "=Dictionary[\"" + attribute.ColumnName + "\"]"; //_objectInstances.First()[attribute.ColumnName].ToString();
            textBoxTable.Size = new SizeU(Unit.Inch(1.1), Unit.Inch(0.3));
            this.table1.Body.SetCellContent(0, i++, textBoxTable);
            this.table1.Items.AddRange(new ReportItemBase[] {textBoxTable, textboxGroup});
        }


    }
```

Which is the correct way to bind to a dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did is convert to a DataTable, and bind to it instead:

```
        var table = new DataTable();            

        //Create table columns
        _objectInstances.First().Columns.ToList().ForEach(a => table.Columns.Add(a, typeof(string)));
        //Create table rows
        _objectInstances.ToList().ForEach(i => table.Rows.Add(i.Dictionary.Values.ToArray()));


        table1.DataSource = table;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try: dictionary.Values.ToList() as your datasource

Comment: I can't, each object (ObjectInstance) has a dictionary, I need to bind to the collection of ObjectInstance's

Comment: Are you wanting to display the data hierarchtically?

Comment: no, just tabular data, the values of the dictionary are the values that should go in the cells

Comment: oh then, just something like: foreach (List<string> list in List.Select(myClass => myClass.Dictionary.Values.ToList())) { result.AddRange(list); } should work